# Getting unique values in excel from table with multiple equivalent values

Tags: excel, charts

I am not an excel expert, but I have been searching for days on a method to repeatably pull non-zero entries from a 2 column table. The reason it has to be repeatable (and hence can't use filtering) is that I have about 50 pie charts with different data sets I need to create so that the charts only have slices that are greater than zero.

Here is an example of the source data, which I have pulled from a few thousand rows of raw entries

```
| Possession type observed      | Count |
| ------------------------------|--------
|Handheld device                 27
|Backback                        53
|Baby stroller                    5
|Walking aid                      1
|Headphones                       5
|Wheelchair or mobility device    2
|umbrella                         1
|Bundle buggy                     0
|book                             0
|DVD                              1
|purse & holding keys             0
|handbag                          1
|clutch wallet                    0
|white paper                      0
|grocery bag                      0
|purse                            0
|holding newspaper                0
|None of these                   83
```

I haven't found a satisfactory solution to build a pie chart out of the data above that removes zeros, so I went ahead and tried to create a summary chart only listing values > zero.
But my problem is that I can pull non-zero entries out, when it comes to the entries with the *same* value (e.g baby stroller and headphones both have a value of 5), I can't grab baby stroller, then headphones.

Ideally I would like the summary chart to look like this:

```
| Possession type observed      | Count |
| ------------------------------|--------
|Handheld device                 27
|Backback                        53
|Baby stroller                    5
|Walking aid                      1
|Headphones                       5
|Wheelchair or mobility device    2
|umbrella                         1
|DVD                              1
|handbag                          1
|None of these                   83
```

Thanks so much in advance for any assistance!

Comment: And how are you pulling out the non-zero data?

Comment: That is part of my problem. I tried to index match values >0 but it selects the first value.

Comment: I do not see any formula in your question that can accomplish that task.  Please read the HELP pages for information as to [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: However, I think the Pivot Chart solution will be the easiest for you to implement.

Comment: Hi Ron, please help with Pie chart to suppress zero values along with the category - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47069256/how-to-suppress-category-in-excel-pie-chart-for-zero-values

Answer (score -1):

To get the desired output follow these steps:

**Step1:** Select the data
**Step2:** Choose pivot chart from insert tab,follow the wizard to create the pivot table and chart where you want them **or** hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>  +  <kbd>D</kbd> +  <kbd>P</kbd> and 3 times <kbd>enter</kbd> 
**Step3:** Change the chart type to pie from the Design tab
**Step4:** Drag the 'Possession type observed' field to the 'Axis' area
**Step5:** Drag the 'Count' field to the 'value' area as well as 'report filter' area
**Step6:** Filter out 0 using the dropdown on the chart